# Firefox and Chromium Won't Start in Ubuntu 22.04 with Nouveau Driver

Tags: firefox, chromium, nouveau, 22.04

I just did a clean install of Ubuntu 22.04 on two machines with Nvidia video cards.

With the default nouveau video driver, neither Firefox or Chromium (both snaps) will start.

Firefox gives the following error when started from Terminal:

```
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.

(firefox:2324): Gdk-WARNING **: 13:50:57.016: The program 'firefox' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadAlloc'.
  (Details: serial 509 error_code 11 request_code 146 (unknown) minor_code 7)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the GDK_SYNCHRONIZE environment
   variable to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
Exiting due to channel error.
```

and Chromium shows the following:

```
[2804:2804:0421/135208.578463:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(377)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[2804:2804:0421/135208.603047:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(275)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
... repeats
```

Both Firefox and Chromium work fine if I switch to the Nvidia 390 proprietary driver.

I got the same error with Firefox using the Live USB.

I would report these as a bug, but I'm not sure where to do so; bugzilla.mozilla.org or somewhere for Ubuntu? And Chromium?

Comment: You may have better luck using Xorg instead of Wayland: https://askubuntu.com/a/1403670/558158

Comment: @vanadium, if I select Xorg, then Firefox works with nouveau, so you're right. Does that mean the package with the bug is actually Wayland?

Comment: The problem is Wayland.

Comment: Thanks @vanadium. I'll take a look at the bug reports for it, and see if adding one would help.

Comment: A friend of mine is getting this error with an NVidia 1060 3GB on freshly installed Ubuntu 22.04. Switching to Xorg fixes it.

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved this without changing to Xorg.

If you can start Firefox in safe-mode then disabling hardware acceleration may work for you as it has for me.

```
$firefox -safe-mode
```

Comment: Nice catch! I wish my only issue was with Firefox. I'm stuck with Xorg because I use Chromium and some other snaps that are also affected. I've also got the [XDG Desktop issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/1985), which using Xorg fixes.

Comment: Solution got from internet. Well, my problem is that by using nvidia proprietary driver my monitor is not recognized. Stucked with nouveau and without hardware acceleration for photo manipulation software and games.

Answer (score 0):

- *Step1* : Log out and then go to login screen.
- *Step2* : type username enter.
- *Step3* : press the gear button and select "Ubuntu on Xorg".

**Try now , it will work**