# Upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 left my box without sound, graphics and network. Any ideas?

Tags: networking, kernel, 22.04

Just finished upgrading (from Ubuntu 21.10), and it left the box broken in several ways, in an unusable state, see details below.

I have a Z690 gigabyte motherboard, intel alder lake i7, nvidia gpu (of a previous generation).

The upgrade left me with 3 kernels to boot from:

1. If I boot the kernel 5.15.0-27-generic, it freezes just after the message of "loading initial ramdisk"
2. If I boot the kernel 5.13.0-40-generic, it boots on a safe graphics, very low resolution, no sound, no ethernet devices (so no internet).
3. If I boot the kernel 5.13.0-19-generic it also fails, but a little after the boot splash screen ... and then freezes.

`$ ip -a`

Only shows `lo` and `docker0` interfaces (no ethernet one). But the `lspci` shows a `Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co. Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller (rev 05)`, that used to work on the previous version.

Any suggestions ? I'm assuming the first thing to fix is the network.
Many thanks!

Comment: I downloaded Ubuntu 22.04 to an USB and booted from it. And network seems to work there, but the graphics are crazy, they look as described in this post:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403595/ubuntu-22-04-graphics-problem

Comment: If I try to boot from the USB with "Safe graphics", it loops on a screen: "Oh no! Something has gone wrong." ...

Comment: Ok, before I logged into the XWindows when booting from USB, I went to the console (control+alt+F1), and using the secret user "ubuntu" (no password) I got a prompt.

After that I used the instructions below to properly chroot (with the proper --bind mounts) to my hard drive installation. So now I can `apt install` stuff from the console.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery

Now I just need to find what I need to do to fix this :( ...

Comment: Nothing I came up with had any effect -- mostly I was trying to install everying nvidia-510, after adding `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa -y`.

Comment: I also installed manually kernels v5.15.37 and v5.17.5 from https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/  But both of them freeze very early in the boot process, just after the message `Loading initial ramdisk ...` is printed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I fixed it, by changing in `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf` the line `MODULES=most` to `MODULES=dep` and then regenerating the `initrd` images.

I can only assume that there is some bug in one of the modules. I'm now booting the newer 5.17.5 kernel that I installed earlier, and it seems working (even with NVidia driver) as before.

After changing the configuration file, I regenerated the initrd with:

```
    $ update-initramfs -v -c -k 5.17.5-051705-generic
    ...
    $ update-grub
```