# Ubuntu 22.04 external displays stopped working

Tags: drivers, graphics, multiple-monitors, 22.04

Today I used my Laptop with Ubuntu 22.04 with 2 external screens, everything worked fine. I turned off the Machine, a few hours later the screens was not recognized (and the icon of my terminal wasn't loaded).

So I purged the proprietary NVIDIA drivers and switched to the default open source ones. After reboot one of my external screens showed the Ubuntu logo during shutdown and startup. The screen is now found by `xrandr`:

```
xrandr --listmonitors 
Monitors: 3
 0: +*XWAYLAND2 1920/380x1080/210+0+0  XWAYLAND2
 1: +XWAYLAND0 1920/480x1080/270+1920+0  XWAYLAND0
 2: +XWAYLAND1 1920/480x1080/270+3840+0  XWAYLAND1
```

But there is no output. Maybe somone can help?

Answer (score 0):

While examining apt install log (/var/log/apt/history.log) there was some nvidia display drivers removed by /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade.Unfortunately I can't tell details because I newly Installed Ubuntu (what doesn't worked^) because my displays did work out of the box the first time.

I found a solution here:
[Ubuntu 22.04 graphics problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403595/ubuntu-22-04-graphics-problem)

I used this solution:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo dpkg --configure -a


sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-515
reboot
```

Now all my screens are working again.
Don't forget to add the key from 3rd party drivers at boot or won't work.

The display link is not using WAYLAND anymore:

```
xrandr --listmonitors
 0: +*DP-1-0.3 1920/476x1080/268+1920+0  DP-1-0.3
 1: +eDP-1 1920/381x1080/214+0+0  eDP-1
 2: +DP-1-0.2 1920/476x1080/268+3840+0  DP-1-0.2
```